# How is it ensured, that parents of children attending wizarding schools in Harry Potter don't get into trouble for skipping regular school

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

As far as I'm informed, some amount of schooling is mandatory for children in the UK and many other civilized countries, and their parents could get into a lot of trouble, if the children did not attend the school.

How is it ensured that parents of children attending Hogwarts or other wizarding schools don't get into the same king of trouble, since their kids do not attend a regular "muggle" school?

Comment: Wizard schools are known of and approved by the UK government.  When a child goes off to wizard school, this is registered with the govt via the minister of magic.  So presumably wizard schools are seen as valid alternate schools.

Comment: @Tim That would be a good answer, especially if you have sources! :)

Comment: @Bellatrix I haven't read any official sources, but I came to the same conclusion as Tim based on the first chapter of HBP, "The Other Minister".

Comment: @asymptotically Yes, I think that's at least part of the right answer too! :)